# Rails 3.1, jQuery: Append data to a form before sending it out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, coffeescript

I read [this issue](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/168) in [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) because I want to add some data to the form before sending it out.

The instructions seemed pretty simple: Hook onto `before:send` and do what you will to the form. I did it this way:

```
form.live "ajax:before", () ->
  form.data('params', sortableList.nestedSortable('serialize'))
  console.log "data we're sending along: " + form.data('params') # here I see the data I want to append to the form
```

The `POST` though doesn't contain any of that data I added to `data-params`:

```
Started POST "/admin/site/nav_items/render_event_response?source=menu_item_tree&type=submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-29 20:48:11 +0800
  Processing by Admin::Site::NavItemsController#render_event_response as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"sV8eEMpIVicbmT0nAfDdChgpRMyI5yR/N6m5VLk3+/Q=", "source"=>"menu_item_tree", "type"=>"submit"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  ...snip...
```

Did I understand [that issue](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/168) wrong? **How do I go about appending data to the form before sending it out?**

Thanks!

Comment: Was getting rather confused there until I realised coffeescript was involved...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [issue you are refering to](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/168)

You're missing the critical part. `ajax:before` callback accepts 3 parameters, one of which you should be editing editing.

Your code should look like this (probably... I haven't tested it)

```
form.live "ajax:before", (event,xhr,settings) ->
  settings.data('params', sortableList.nestedSortable('serialize'))
```